# D3 Parallel Coordinates : Drawing two lines to show a range and shading the region between them

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I have a 3 axes in the parallel coordinates Name, Frequency Range and Band..I am trying to do two things here:

```
{
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "name": "Band2",
                "frequencyRange": "20-52",
                "Band": "FM"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "name": "Band3",
                "frequencyRange": "1-11",
                "Band": "AM"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "name": "Band4",
                "frequencyRange": "1.5-4.25",
                "Band": "AM"
            }
        }
```

1. Draw two lines to show the range (Eg : For Band 2 : A line connecting Band2,20,FM   and another line connecting Band2,52,FM
2. Shade the region between the two lines.

Sample : http://lalithkaushik.com/d3/

I tried to paste the script part here, but stack overflow would not let me do it. http://lalithkaushik.com/d3/code.html

Any suggestions would really help and appreciated..

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you're using a particular library to render the parallel coordinates chart (I believe this one: https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/), and as far as I can tell that library doesn't support what you're trying to do.  You may need to break into that code and learn what it's doing with the underlying D3 primitives.  Look here for an example that may be similar to what you're trying to do: http://www.jasondavies.com/parallel-sets/